# Android - Are App Cache + App Data automatically cleared when user uninstalls an Android App?

Tags: android, caching, memory, uninstallation, android-memory

When uninstalling an Android App, are App Cache + App Data automatically cleared? Or are they kept in memory on the device in case the user installs the app sometime in the future?

Comment: you need to keep it in app memory or internal memory otherwise it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they will be removed automatically, but not if you save it on SD Card.
For example the `getChacheDir` will be saved at `/data/data/yourapp/cache/`.

App data like `SQLite`, `File`, `SharedPreferences` etc. Will also be saved at `/data/data/yourapp/` (assuming you don't create a `File` with `/sdcard` path).

When you install your application it will be saved at `/data/data/yourapp` and when uninstallning your application `/data/data/yourapp` will be deleted. Actually, I can't find documentation on this, I just know this by experience. But you can google around for other peoples answer to support my statement, as soon as I find a documentation for this I will edit this answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you provide a source that states that app data/cache are automatically removed?

Comment: @Momen: As soon as I find a documentation I will post it, but check my edited answer.